# Accessibility: Whats the preferred standard compliant behavior for a drop down to be considered accessible?

Tags: angular, accessibility, section508

I would like for the first item in the drop down to be read by the screen reader(NVDA or Jaws). Currently when tabbing through, the screen reader reads the label: "Sports Cars" and audibly says "list". Is that what is preferred or should it read the first item? I am using a custom angular component.

```
<my-dropdown [fieldData]="this.getMyfieldData" label="Sports Cars"></mydropdown>
```

Comment: When you say "drop down", do you mean a select element, or a navigation menu? Also, the angular code you posted is no help at all. Maybe you could post your rendered HTML instead?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All the answers you seek are [here](https://www.w3.org/TR/wai-aria-practices-1.1/). First decide whether you are making a combobox or a listbox. Then make an effort to duplicate the examples with your output.

Also be sure to read section 6 about keyboard input.